# MVC Model loses binding

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an issue with MVC (new to this, coming from MVVM in WPF).

I have a combobox in my cshtml file that lets the user choose a country from the list. However, in my model when I try to fetch the country from the list the collection is null.

```
<div class="inputs">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SelectedCountry)
    <div class="input-box">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CountryID, Model.AvailableCountries)
    </div>
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SelectedCountry)
</div>
```

As you can see I bind the selected value to CountryID. In my model I use this CountryID to fetch the name from the list of countries and set the SelectedCountry string to whatever the user has picked.

The problem is when I try to fetch the country from the list in my model the list is null.

**The list of countries in my model:**

```
public IList<SelectListItem> AvailableCountries 
{ 
    get
    {
        if (_availableCountries == null)
            _availableCountries = new List<SelectListItem>();
        return _availableCountries;
    }
    set
    {
        _availableCountries = value;
    }
}
```

**And the population of the list of countries in my controller.**

```
foreach (var c in _countryService.GetAllCountries())
{
    model.AvailableCountries.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = c.Name, Value = c.Id.ToString() });
}
```

Also as you see in the cshtml, the value is bound to CountryIID and the code for that property is:

```
public int CountryID
{
    get
    {
        return _countryID;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_countryID != value)
        {
            _countryID = value;
            List<SelectListItem> _list = new List<SelectListItem>(AvailableCountries);
                SelectedCountry = _list.Find(x => x.Value == _countryID.ToString()).Text;
        }
    }
}
```

/Peter

Comment: This is just the view, where is the underlying logic?

Answer (score 1):

Your binding for dropdownlistfor is not proper.

You are suppose to provide field name whose value will be bind by Razor engine to dropdownlist for that you need to provide the property name that you want to bind in dropdown. Try this out

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ActionId, new SelectList(@Model.AvailableCountries,"AccountID","AccountName"))
```

where AccountId,AccountName is the property field inside `AvailableCountries` where AccountName values will be show in page and AccountId will be bind on select.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Well as you can see in my updated post above the items in the list are actually SelectListItems so they are mapped by standard I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue by taking care of the CountryId and translating it in my controller instead.
Then just repopulating the AvailableCountries list if the model was not valid and send it back to the view.

Comment: That's exactly how you are supposed to take care of it.  Coming from MVVM/WPF can be a little challenging because of the statelessness of the web.  Once you serve up the view (populated with data), if you post your data and there is a problem with the ModelState not being valid, you need to manually repopulate the dropdowns because that information isn't posted back with the POST.